# Testing JSON translation files with Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm using the ngx-translate library to provide multiple languages on an Angular application. After finding a couple of missing translated strings when switching the language, I decided to add some basic tests to the files containing the translated strings. Basically, I want to test that all the language files have the same keys.

My translation files are separated in several folders: `app`, `labels` and `wizards` (so far), with each folder containing an `es.json` and `en.json` file. To test all the files, this is what I do:

**i18n.spec.ts**

```js
fdescribe("i18n language files tests", () => {
  // Global app translations
  let appEs: any;
  let appEn: any;
  // Panels translations
  let panelsEs: any;
  let panelsEn: any;
  // Wizards translations
  let wizardsEs: any;
  let wizardsEn: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    appEs = require('./app/es.json');
    appEn = require('./app/en.json');

    panelsEs = require('./panels/es.json');
    panelsEn = require('./panels/en.json');

    wizardsEs = require('./wizards/es.json');
    wizardsEn = require('./wizards/en.json');
  });

  it('should have the same keys for all language files', () => {
    // Global app translations
    let keysEs = getObjKeys(appEs);
    let keysEn = getObjKeys(appEn);
        
    expect(findMissingKeys(appEn, keysEs)).toEqual([]);
    expect(findMissingKeys(appEs, keysEn)).toEqual([]);

    // Panels translations
    keysEs = getObjKeys(panelsEs);
    keysEn = getObjKeys(panelsEn);
        
    expect(findMissingKeys(panelsEn, keysEs)).toEqual([]);
    expect(findMissingKeys(panelsEs, keysEn)).toEqual([]);

    // Wizards translations
    keysEs = getObjKeys(wizardsEs);
    keysEn = getObjKeys(wizardsEn);
        
    expect(findMissingKeys(wizardsEn, keysEs)).toEqual([]);
    expect(findMissingKeys(wizardsEs, keysEn)).toEqual([]);
  });
});
```

As you can see, I load each JSON file using `require` and then, for each pair of language "sections" (app, panels, wizards) I get its keys and I make sure that both languages have exactly the same.

This is working fine, but, as `require` doesn't work with variables, the code it's quite repetitive and adding a new language subfolder is really cumbersome, as I have to add it in several parts of the code.

Any ideas on how I could simplify this process? Thanks!

Comment: "attranslate" is a modern tool that is specifically designed to detect missing translations or other mistakes: https://github.com/fkirc/attranslate

Comment: Hi! I'll have a look, thanks for your suggestion!